# Injecting div label to every <a> link

Tags: css, dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on browser extension which shows some info below every  link using injected javascript. I want to use color div block with small icons and labels inside. The problem is that some pages will override default CSS styles for my injected elements also not sure that all blocks will have right position (below their links). I'm using Chrome. Any suggestions what to use for any page markup?

Comment: read this: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 2):

!important is the last resort, in my opinion.

I would first suggest the following:

1. Add distinct CSS classes to the div labels, so that no other CSS file could override it.  Example:  yourextensionname-label could be the class name for the div label.
2. Load your CSS file last.
3. If the above fails, use inline styles.

Comment: +1 for point 3. Create "class" variables in your JavaScript code and simply associate them to `element.style` (e.g. `var container_css = "float: left;"`). Not the cleanest way, but by far the safest to guarantee a consistent L&F.

Answer (score 0):

Add `!important` styles for every style rule you need (even the defaults).
This will override anything the page does.

Comment: But still need to specify all possible CSS propeties fields for every element, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Some of your problems may be because you are placing block elements in an inline element, which can get kicked out into their own elements instead of rendered where you want.

1) If you aren't worried about older browsers (ie6/ie7), you could set the link style to "display:inline-block;". This will let you store other block elements inside it. You can the inject smaller divs/images inside.

2) Depending on your layout, you can set the link display to block and then float the links to the left for a similar effect, but that won't work well if they are in a block of regular text.

3) Finally, you may have to use javascript to absolutely position the divs just below the links.

**update:**

I missed the browser extension part my first time reading the question. You should set very specific css variables, and probably use absolute positioning. You may have to use !important, but that should only happen if you are sure your styles won't bleed over onto the original page content.